# C# xaml System.BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I have a WPF app that yesterday was building and running fine.
Today when I opened it up I am getting this error:

http://oi61.tinypic.com/vzady8.jpg

It seems to happen before my xaml cs code is running since no breakpoints work.
I assume it is to do with loading the assemblies.

Here is the full error, look at the inner exception as I think this is the real error:

http://pastebin.com/xUuamwae

It might be to do with the WindowsBase dll as it seems to highlight that line, or maybe it's the inner exception that is causing the WindowsBase to die here?

Inner exception:

```
InnerException: System.BadImageFormatException
HResult=-2147024885
Message=Could not load file or assembly 
'Cognex.InSight.Controls.Display, 
Version=4.9.2511.0,  Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=6b9774afddb09935' or one of its dependencies. 
An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/383138/BadImageFormatException-x-i-x)?

Comment: All my projects are set to any cpu. How would I check if the dll is set to any? The properties of the file don't seem to show it. thanks

Answer (score 4):

I changed the project to x86 and it worked.